# Check if Array at position contains another array

Tags: excel, vba

Please look at the code below. I am reading JSON using [this code](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/640780-parse-json-excel-visual-basic-applications.html) which works great, but, I am now trying to dump the resulting array into columns / rows. Some of my returned JSON values, contain arrays in them (example below "cat_list").

I am not able to understand why in the code below:

```
MsgBox "ITEM VALUE... " & p("data")(Row)(Col_Data)(1)
```

shows the value '20' (which is correct for the JSON input below), but the code snippet:

```
If IsArray(p("data")(Row)(Col_Data)) Then
```

resolves to FALSE, which then causes the ELSE part of the code to fail. Why is IsArray not working?

My JSON input looks like this:

```
{... "layout_file":"category.html","cat_list":[20, 30, 25], ...}
```

The code snippet:

```
Row = 1

For Each Item In p("data")
    Col = 1

    For Each Col_Data In p("data")(Row)

        If Col_Data = "cat_list" Then
            MsgBox "ITEM VALUE... " & p("data")(Row)(Col_Data)(1)   <-- SUCCESSFULLY PRINTS SUB-ARRAY VALUE "20"
        End If

        If IsArray(p("data")(Row)(Col_Data)) Then   <-- FAILS TO DETECT SUB-ARRAY
            Cells(Row + 1, Col) = "["

            For Each SubArrayData In p("data")(Row)(Col_Data)(SubArray)
                Cells(Row + 1, Col) = Cells(Row + 1, Col) & ", " & p("data")(Row)(Col_Data)(SubArray)
            Next SubArrayData

            Cells(Row + 1, Col) = Cells(Row + 1, Col) & "]"
        Else
            Cells(Row + 1, Col) = p("data")(Row)(Col_Data)   <-- CODE FAILS HERE ONLY WHEN ITEM CONTAINS ARRAY, BUT SUCCESSFULLY PRINTS VALUE "20" IN MSG BOX ABOVE
        End If

        Col = Col + 1
    Next Col_Data

    Row = Row + 1
Next Item
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which line gives the `Object Defined Error` error ? Is it possible for you to share the workbook ?

Comment: Hi @Santosh the line giving the error is "Cells(Row + 1, Col) = p("data")(Row)(Col_Data)" in the ELSE statement from the IsArray comparion (see above). This is happening because "Cells(Row + 1, Col) = p("data")(Row)(Col_Data)" is an array but IsArray is not picking it up in the code above.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `IsArray()` function  to check if a variable is an array.

[image]

sample code

```
Sub testArray()

Dim i() As Integer
Dim j As Integer


MsgBox IsArray(i)
MsgBox IsArray(j)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Santosh, thanks for the reply, but I am still getting the same error. The message is OBJECT DEFINED error. I am expecting an array in the position, see above pls. Thanks!

Comment: @user2469528 `If IsArray(p("data")(Row)(Col_Data)) Then ....do something....End If`   Try this.